# can't use Hashes from Stylus

Tags: stylus

I read http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/hashes.html and none of the examples not working for me. 
For exapmle

```
foo = {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      raz: 10px
    }
  }
}


qux = "raz"
padding
    padding foo["bar"].baz[qux]
```

a compilation error

```
expected "indent", got "eos"
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use colon when calling hashes' values, as otherwise Stylus couldn't differentiate between selectors and hashes. So,

```
foo = {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      raz: 10px
    }
  }
}


qux = "raz"
padding
    padding: foo["bar"].baz[qux]
```

should work ok.