# Stylus: store variables in an object

Tags: stylus

I have the following object/hash for example:

```
$colors = {
   black: #000,
   gray: #666
}
```

When I try and do something like this, I get an `expected "indent", got "outdent"` error.

```
body
    background-color $colors.gray
```

Is there a way to do something like this? I think its just easier to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415015/cant-use-hashes-from-stylus

Answer (score 0):

`background-color: $colors['gray']`

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Well. I'll add the explanation. the answer is adding colon after property name. SO when you using hash you need to write it completely 

color: $myColor.red not color $myColor.red

note the working one is the "color:"